# Is there any option to use Amazon Cloud Drive from terminal (Linux)?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, amazon-web-services, cloud-storage

As you probably know, Amazon did not release any Cloud Drive client for Linux. Is there any other option to access ACD from terminal?

Comment: It looks like the answer, even if it seems to be "yes," is, in fact, "no."  *You may use the Service only to store, retrieve, manage, and access Your Files for personal, non-commercial purposes using the features and functionality we make available...* http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/?nodeId=201376540

Comment: Not sure why this would mean you can't access it from the terminal. Amazon is providing functionality, which may (in the future) very well be run from the terminal. It is also providing an open API, which somebody may wrap inside a command-line application (see my answer below).

Comment: The best solution I see (which I'm in the process of setting up) is to set up an SSHFS mount from my mac and use the mac Amazon Drive client.

Answer (score 23):

At the time of asking the answer was unfortunately **No**, but no more! You can now easily access Amazon Cloud Drive from the terminal using an OpenSource client called [`acd_cli`](https://github.com/yadayada/acd_cli), which is written in Python (3) and runs under Windows / Linux / Mac. There was a list of authorised apps here: https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/apps but it now only shows official Amazon clients for MacOS and Windows.

These are mostly "cloud-to-cloud-sync" services and absolutely not what you are looking for, though. Even the Amazon build app for Mac OS X, which actually is a stand-alone uploader, does not provide a command-line-interface and you can not upload files from the console.

The only hope is an open REST-based [API](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/cloud-drive) that allows interaction with Amazon Cloud Drive, which is good news, as it essentially means, anybody could build a client for it.

One app called [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com) also supports Amazon Cloud Drive by now [due to user requests](https://expandrive.uservoice.com/forums/205560-expandrive-feature-requests/suggestions/3991069-expandrive-should-support-amazon-cloud-drive-and-a). That doesn't help much, though, since they also don't have a Linux version of their (commercial) app, yet, but they are also working on that [apparently](https://expandrive.uservoice.com/forums/205560-expandrive-feature-requests/suggestions/5492206-expandrive-for-linux) (originally to be released mid-summer 2015). There are a number of similar products such as [Netdrive](http://www.netdrive.net) (only supports Windows). The (discontinued) [DragonDisk](http://www.dragondisk.com/download-amazon-s3-client-google-cloud-storage-client.html) already has linux command-line binaries and supports:

> Amazon S3®, Google Cloud Storage®, and all cloud storage services that provides compatibility with Amazon S3 API

You could of course try to run either of those through [wine](https://www.winehq.org).

There is also some [software](http://www.gladinet.com/p/moreaboutdesktop.htm) that [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5788550/mount-your-amazon-cloud-drive-space-like-a-network-folder-in-windows) mentions to be used under Windows. I imagine you could use [wine](https://www.winehq.org) to run it (or any of the former tools) to see if you can make those work.

If all this doesn't make you happy right now:

There is another idea I thought about: **Terminal-based web browsing**. Install [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net) or any alternative (lynx, links2, etc.) and try it out - I didn't get very far, but I haven't tested all of them and you can at least log into the website from your terminal-based browser. I also couldn't test the image-rendering capabilities (you need xterm for that). [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/103574/how-to-browse-from-the-linux-terminal-with-w3m/) is a decent guide.

```
sudo apt-get install w3m w3m-img
w3m cloud.amazon.com
```

The problem is that it doesn't display any files and you will have trouble with the drag & drop upload functionality. So we are generally out of luck.

Comment: Expandrive added support in version 5.

Comment: @ArturBodera sure, but they are still lacking linux support

Comment: This is back to being "NO" as Amazon has broken access from all tools like this.

Answer (score 20):

I've been using http://rclone.org/ with much success. I find it quite mature and robust. It also includes bandwidth throttling that works!

Edit: Please note that this is no longer the case. [Amazon Drive has banned rclone](https://forum.rclone.org/t/rclone-has-been-banned-from-amazon-drive/2314) and this appears to be permanent.

Comment: Please be careful while recommending software or services as they might appear as spam. Please consider reading http://superuser.com/help/promotion

Comment: Point taken, however, the original poster was asking for software recommendations. I'm not affiliated with these guys in anyway.

Comment: You are doing okay. Just a friendly note

Comment: This appears to work well so far.  I plan to script around it and build an automated backup system for my network using this.  Thanks for the tip Matt

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. Provide more than just a link, for eample some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: rclone is awesome & working well for me. I like how it resembles rsync. Thanks @matt604

Comment: Please note that this is no longer the case. Amazon Cloud has banned rclone and this appears to be permanent.  [rclone forum post](https://forum.rclone.org/t/rclone-has-been-banned-from-amazon-drive/2314)

Answer (score 5):

Apparently there's another newbie command line access project as well.

The [ACD 3rd Party Tools](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/cloud-drive/content/third-party-tools) page lists [acd_cli](https://github.com/yadayada/acd_cli), a command line access tool in the alpha stages.

Comment: I am using this one as well nowadays and it's pretty neat - works fairly well and since it's written in python it will work under linux (as asked by OP)

Answer (score 4):

There is a command line program called `drivesink`:

https://github.com/caseymrm/drivesink

https://drivesink.appspot.com/

For GUI there is now Boxcryptor:

https://www.boxcryptor.com/en/blog/boxcryptor-now-supports-amazon-cloud-drive

They have a portable Linux client here:

https://www.boxcryptor.com/en/boxcryptor-portable-download

Answer (score 1):

There is a [FUSE driver](https://github.com/handyman5/acd_fuse) for Amazon Cloud Drive which exists but the results of using it are (so far) inconsistent.

The driver is [based on some earlier work](https://code.google.com/p/pyamazonclouddrive/) done to allow using the Amazon Cloud Drive from python.

However, it appears the REST API for Amazon Cloud Drive has changed since the earlier work was done.

My results using it have been spotty.  I could mount the ACD as a linux mount point and transfer data to it using command line tools (like midnight commander) but I couldn't see the transfer files locally on the linux mount point.  Other times, I couldn't seem them on ACD.

It's a hopeful work in progress at this point.

Comment: Just tested it out, I can see folders but no files ... adding files isn't reflected on the web interface, so I assume something's broken.